# File Uploading In MVC 3 is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I wanted create a form where user will edit there profile and upload an image if they want,
Here is  my View

//Form String `@using(Html.BeginForm("EditProfile","Employee",FormMethod.Post, 
 new { enctype = "multipart/form-data " }))`

//Input HTML  `<input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>`

//Submit`<input type="submit" name="SubmitBtn" value="SaveProfile" />
                        <input type="submit" name="SubmitBtn" value="Cancel" />`

Now My Controller

```
    //Profile Modification
    [Authorize]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditProfile(employer model, string SubmitBtn,HttpFileCollection file)
    {
        switch (SubmitBtn)
        {
            case "SaveProfile":
                try
                {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                    {
                          //the file is always null
                        if (file != null)
                        {
                             //Function I want to Apply on file
                             model.logoname = logouploded(file);  
                            return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Employer");
                        }
                        return RedirectToAction("EditProfile");
                    }
                    //ChangeEmployeeProfile(model);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    ViewBag.warn = ex.Message;
                    return View(model);
                }
                break;
            case "Cancel":
                return RedirectToAction("index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Now no matter what file I upload file is always coming null
I have also tried HttpFileCollectionBase as parameter in Action Function still file was null

Just to mention Model of Employee contains only image file name
because I only want to save image name in database.

Comment: Hi, have you checked in the `Request.Files` collection after post back?

Comment: delete last space in "multipart/form-data " . correct: "multipart/form-data"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change HttpFileCollection type to [HttpPostedFileBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx).

Comment: after correcting whitespace in "multipart/form-data" tried HttpPostedFileBase but now file is cause modelstate.isvalide() to return false.

Comment: Message = "The parameter conversion from type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFileWrapper' to type 'System.Web.HttpPostedFile' failed because no type converter can convert between these types."

Comment: Finally Its work Thanks for help
whitespace in "multipart/form-data" was the problem and parameter was changed to HttpPostedFileBase and its working like charm thank again @peter Kiss